# Is it necessary to release the object?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Here is the code:

```
-(void)myOwnMethod{


    NSString *myString;

    myString = [[NSString alloc]init];

    /*

    Some logic about the String


    */

    [myString release]; //Do I need to release the myString Object?

}
```

As you can see, the myString object is only used in the method, do I need to release it? or it will auto release when the method finish? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need to release it. If you called `alloc`, you must call either `release` or `autorelease`.

Note: If you are using garbage collection (currently only available on OS X, not iOS), then `release` and `autorelease` do nothing, and you do not need to call them. If you are writing memory-managed code (which includes anything written for iOS), then you must call them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Simple rule for every `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy`, you need a `release` or `autorelease`.

This goes for both Objective-C and CoreFoundation objects.